# How to access a private repository using a GitHub App with OAuth?

Tags: github, github-api, github-app, github-oauth

My goal is to be able to list and access private repositories of a user.

For this, I've set up a **GitHub App** to perform some tasks as an app. I have also **enabled** the OAuth capability of my app. I want to make clear that this is a GitHub App with OAuth capabilities, not an OAuth App itself.

In the registered callback, I obtain an `installation_id` that allows me to execute actions on behalf of the app. Additionally, I receive a `code` which I then exchange for a valid `authorization` key to execute actions on behalf of the user.

Despite my attempts to request all repositories using either the installation ID or the authorization code, I'm only able to access public repositories. It appears that private repositories can only be accessed through a Personal Access Token (PAT) or, maybe a dedicated OAuth App. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Listing accessible repos as an app is a two step process:

1. [Get an Installation Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-an-installation-access-token-for-a-github-app) from `https://api.github.com/app/installations/{installation_id}/access_tokens`, authenticating as the App (Bearer authorization, and a JWT signed by the App Private Key. The Installation Access Token expires 1 hour after issuance.
2. [Use the Installation Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/authenticating-to-the-rest-api) as Bearer authorization token to query one of the [available API endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/endpoints-available-for-github-app-installation-access-tokens), such as `/installation/repositories`

You won't be able to list the user's private repositories, but only those he granted your app access to. The that list of repos may include some private repositories, but the app will not have access to private repos it was not granted access to.

You can [access the repos themselves as an app](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation) for clone/fetch/etc using an url like "`https://x-access-token:{intallation_access_token}@{reponame}`".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately I did add the private repository to the accessible repos, but it still skips it. I found multiple other people having the same issue and switching to Github OAuth seem to have fixed the issue. It's a minimally different flow, but still.

Comment: I use this exact recipe for my app and the listing returned is correct (matches the list of repos where the app is enabled, which is a mix of private and public repos), so I can confirm that the procedure, as documented by GitHub, does work.

Comment: @DanielStephens make sure to query the `/installation/respositories` endpoint ("List repositories accessible to the app installation") and not `/users/{username}/repos` ("List repositories for a user")

Comment: That makes absolutely sense, merci!